# Add shortcode in my joomla

Tags: php, joomla3.0, shortcode

I want to add  php shortcode  in joomla3 template like in wordpress (`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[shortcode_id="1"]' ) ?>`).

Is there any way to do that? Help me ,please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **DirectPHP** which is a plugin that allows direct embedding of PHP commands right inside Joomla content page!

> http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/directphp

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any extension you can use this code (for Joomla 3.x):

```
$params = new JObject;
$article = new stdClass;
$article->text = '------> Write/Assign here the text with shortcodes <-----';
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array('text', &$article, &$params, 0));

echo $article->text;
```